# libexecdir in systemd .service file?

Tags: linux, installation, rpm, environment-variables, systemd

I'm deploying something to machines (internally, not for public consumption) using RPMs. Now, in RPM .spec files there's the `%_libexecdir` variable. The package deploys a service binary in that location. How do I have that path automatically be used in the systemd .service file's `ExecStart=` entry? There's no corresponding Bash variable, for example, and I don't know if something like `rpm --eval=%_libexecdir` is a good idea or even possible within the .service.

Comment: Anyone? I'm still stuck on this.